# Golang complaining about unused variable inside for-loop

Tags: go

I have an unused variable inside a for-loop in golang.

I'm actually using it outside the for loop.

Goland keeps complaining about the unused variable.

How do I fix this?

```
var backoffSchedule = []time.Duration{
    1 * time.Second,
    3 * time.Second,
    10 * time.Second,
}
var response *http.Response

for _, backoff := range backoffSchedule {
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err == nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf(os.Stderr, "Request error: %s", err)
    fmt.Printf(os.Stderr, "Retrying in %s", backoff)
    time.Sleep(backoff)

}

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("CRITICAL: API request failed: %s", err)
    os.Exit(2)
}

if response.StatusCode <= 199 || response.StatusCode >= 300 {
    // Non-successful response, alert
    fmt.Printf("CRITICAL: APIv request returned not ok: %s", response.Status)
    os.Exit(2)
```

[image: Unused variable error]

It's also complaining about the unreferenced variable `err`. How do I make them available inside the function.

Comment: there are two solutions for your problem. either you do something with the "response" variable, or you replace is with _, err so it does not get assigned the same as you did in the line above

Comment: You are not using it ourside of the loop. You have 2 variables named `response`. One outside of the loop and another one inside it.

Comment: also, you check for response.StatusCode outside your loop. this might be the underlying issue.

Comment: @super Even if I remove `var response *http.Response`, it's still giving me same error.

Comment: @Underoos Yes, ofc. You are not using the variable inside the loop... so why would removing the outer variable change anything?

Comment: Is there any way to make them available outside for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make the error disappear would be to declare an `err` variable outside the loop:

```
var err error
```

That way, you can assign *existing* variables (rather than declare *new* variables) inside the loop

```
for _, backoff := range backoffSchedule {
    response, err = client.Do(request)
                 ^^^
```

Make sure this is what you want though, as `response` will be, outside the loop, the last value assigned in the loop.

Answer (score 8):

You have two variables named `response`, one inside the loop and another outside the loop.

Here is an example that demonstrates the same issue.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo() (int, error) {
    return 10, nil
}

func main() {
    someValue := 5
    
    if (someValue == 5) {
        someValue, err := foo()
        if (err == nil) {
            fmt.Println("Inside if scope:", someValue)
        }
    }
    
    fmt.Print("Outside if scope:", someValue)
}
```

The issue here is that you are using `:=`, which by default creates a new variable.

If you declare `err` outside of the scope and use `=` your code will work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo() (int, error) {
    return 10, nil
}

func main() {
    someValue := 5
    var err error
    
    if (someValue == 5) {
        someValue, err = foo()
        if (err == nil) {
            fmt.Println("Inside if scope:", someValue)
        }
    }
    
    fmt.Print("Outside if scope:", someValue)
}
```

Another note to how go behaves is that if you are in the same scope as an already existing variable, it works differently.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo() (int, error) {
    return 10, nil
}

func main() {
    someValue := 5
    
    fmt.Println("Before foo:", someValue)
    
    someValue, err := foo()
    if (err == nil) {
        fmt.Print("After foo:", someValue)
    }
}
```

Here we are assigning to the same `someValue` and declaring a new variable `err` at the same time with `:=`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of error detection, maybe you can add a nil check for the `response` variable as well. This might be a solution for you. For eq.

```
if response== nil {
    break
}
```

Please share your preferred or discovered answer to the situation.